# how to winactive WMP in Now Playing mode

Tags: wmp

The below script opens Windows Media Player or activates when it has not been closed clicking the "Minimize" bottom at the "Now Playing" screen. How can I always Winactivate WMP?

```
    #c::   ;opens WMP
       sc=Windows Media Player  ;- window title
  IfWinExist,%sc%
      {
           IfWinNotActive ,%SC%,
           {
           WinActivate,%SC%
           WinWaitActive,%SC%
           }
           Return
      }
      gosub Launch ; Launch WMP
      Return
        Launch:
        ReLaunch:
        Run, C:\Program Files\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe /Task NowPlaying, , , PID
        Winwait, ahk_pid %PID%,,.25
        WinActivate, ahk_pid %PID%
        IfWinNotExist ahk_class WMP Skin Host
            gosub ReLaunch
      Return
```